# Form atrás da barra do Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

O que esta acontecendo e o seguinte, quando configuro o form no c# visual studio 2015 para maximizado, a parte de baixo do form fica por traz da barra de tarefas do windows, como posso fazer pra resolver o problema.

Segue o código:

```
public class frmComissaoPic : Form
{
    ...
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o seu código?

Comment: posso sim claro...

Comment: pra que server isso: `CloseButtonDisabler.DisableCloseButton(this.Handle.ToInt32());` ?

Comment: Essa classe uso para desabilitar o botão X do formulario

Comment: tenta não utilizar isso, e ver se o erro persiste

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Qual a opção que você está usando pra deixar o form maximizado? O form está sem bordas?

Comment: Então ja estou abrindo o form maximizado já, a borda esta como FixedSingle

Comment: O que pude notar e que se eu desabilitar o botão maximizar do form principal e abrir o from direto maximizado ai tenho problemas com a barra de tarefas, agora habilitar o maximizar do form principal e abrir o form sem maximizar ou seja abri-lo normalmente , maximizar pelo botão do form ai ele repeita a barra de tarefas.

Comment: O problema todo esta em desabilitar o botão maximizar no form principal, acabei de fazer um teste aqui, deixei o botão maximizar do form principal habilitado e WindowState deixei pra abrir maximizado, ai sim ele respeito a barra de tarefas.

Comment: Verifica a propriedade do form "IsMdiContainer"

Comment: O código que você colocou não tem nada a ver com o problema.

Comment: antes a pergunta estava mais completa... o problema não é com o `WindowState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o próprio autor da pergunta, o problema só ocorre se essas duas situações ocorrerem simultaneamente:

- O formulário é configurado para iniciar maximizado;
- O botão de maximizar está desabilitado, i.e.: `this.MaximizeBox = false;`

Isso é feito através da IDE, que por baixo dos panos gera os trechos de código presentes na pergunta e nesta resposta.

Testei e consegui reproduzir o comportamento em .NET 4.5, com Visual Studio 2013. Formulários que não possuem o botão de maximizar habilitado, quando maximizados, fica por trás da barra de tarefas.

Eu acredito que maximizar algo que não pode ser maximizado é um absurdo, e forçar o usuário a utilizar uma aplicação que ocupa toda a tela - principalmente se os componentes de interface não precisarem disso - não deve ser encorajado. Minha sugestão é para aplicar um tamanho mínimo ao formulário se necessário, mas não fazer nada além disso com relação a tamanho.

Comment: Vlw pelas respostas. Vou rever aqui o comportamento das minhas telas para aprimorar o máximo possível o meu programa..

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta do Renan, que está certo sobre a causa do comportamento do Form, você pode contornar isso, desabilitando o botão, ou os botões da `ControlBox` no evento `Load` do Form.

O Form pode estar definido para iniciar maximizado, porém com a `ControlBox` e `MaximizeBox` habilitados.

No evento `Load`, desabilita o que for necessário.

Comment: Esta resposta deveria ser a correta.