# Form Visual Studio Cobrindo a Barra de Tarefas do Windows ou Ficando Atrás da Barra de Tarefas

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Tenho uma aplicação que utilizo a propriedade FormBorderStyle = none, porem esta acontecendo que no windows 10 minha barra de status (statusBar) que fica na parte inferior fica atras da barra de tarefas e no windows 7 acaba cobrindo , o que posso fazer para ajustar no tamanho correto?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Form atrás da barra do Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250274/form-atr%c3%a1s-da-barra-do-windows)

Comment: NÃO, NÃO, SITUAÇÃO SEMELHANTE, SOLUÇÃO DIFERENTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente definir o tamanho máximo para a janela ser a [área segura da área de trabalho](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx). Você precisará incluir as duas referências:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

E coloque esses procedimentos na hora de carregar o `Form`:

```
Rectangle workingAreaRect = Screen.WorkingArea;
Size workingAreaSize = workingAreaRect.Size;

Form1.MaximumSize = workingAreaSize;
Form1.TopMost = false; // faz com que o Form não seja exibido na frente da Taskbar
```

Estes métodos acima irão fazer com que o tamanho do `Form` se estenda até a área segura do monitor

Comment: Deu certo Consegui! Muito obrigado. Abraço